# Test if a class has an attribute?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, attributes

I'm trying to do a little Test-First development, and I'm trying to verify that my classes are marked with an attribute:

```
[SubControllerActionToViewDataAttribute]
public class ScheduleController : Controller
```

How do I unit test that the class has that attribute assigned to it?

Answer (score 161, accepted):

check that

```
Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(ScheduleController),
    typeof(SubControllerActionToViewDataAttribute))
```

isn't null (`Assert.IsNotNull` or similar)

(the reason I use this rather than `IsDefined` is that most times I want to validate some properties of the attribute too....)

Comment: to only check if the attribute is present, which is usually all that is needed for parameterless/propertyless attributes, it's cheaper to use .IsDefined, as it will query the metadata, and not deserialize and instantiate the attribute object.

Comment: As is the point about IsDefined being cheaper... but in most cases (and in particular unit tests) you are unlikely to notice the difference. Maybe if it was a tight loop in production code...

Comment: @Marc- I agree about that the difference in performance would probably not be noticeable in a unit test. I'd get the attribute if I needed to use it, which as you say is the scenario in most cases. I recently used IsDefined in a framework I was writing to exclude a column in a dropdown of sortable fields- this worked well as I didn't need to use to the attribute itself.

Comment: How can we test the same for a method?

Answer (score 97):

The same you would normally check for an attribute on a class.

Here's some sample code.

```
typeof(ScheduleController)
.IsDefined(typeof(SubControllerActionToViewDataAttribute), false);
```

I think in many cases testing for the existence of an attribute in a unit test is wrong. As I've not used MVC contrib's sub controller functionality I can't comment whether it is appropriate in this case though.

Comment: Did +1 and then noticed error. It should be .IsDefined(typeof(Type), false);

Comment: @alexanderb you are of course right. I've updated my answer now. I must of not checked my answer against the compiler at the time! Thanks for pointing out the error

Comment: this approach is faster then previous

Answer (score 23):

It is also possible to use generics on this:

```
var type = typeof(SomeType);
var attribute = type.GetCustomAttribute<SomeAttribute>();
```

This way you do not need another `typeof(...)`, which can make the code cleaner.

Comment: This does not work for me. Which `using` .. am I missing?

Comment: @Scanzy I'm not sure, are you not using a IDE? (Usually they suggest the correct `using`) What error do you get?

Comment: ok, [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/hh194292(v=vs.110).aspx) I found the `GetCustomAttribute<SomeAttribute>` method is avaliable from .NET 4.5 and my IDE was set to 3.5 so everything is clear now

Answer (score 13):

I know this thread is really old, but if somebody stumble upon on it you may find [fluentassertions](https://github.com/dennisdoomen/fluentassertions/wiki#type-method-and-property-assertions) project very convenient for doing this kind of assertions.

```
typeof(MyPresentationModel).Should().BeDecoratedWith<SomeAttribute>();
```